# Generate Random Integers

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dice rolling game. I want to generate a random integer in the range of the number of dice I have multiplied by the number of sides the dice has. For example, if two dice were played with three sides, then there could be any number between 2 and 6.

Here is my code; when I put in, for example one dice and two sides, it prints numbers upwards of 13. The problem is that it doesn't create an integer between the amount of sides and dice.

```
condition = "Start" 
while condition == "Start": 
Dice = int(input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (atleast 1)"))
Sides = int(input("Please select number of sides on dice you would like to use (atleast 2)"))
if Dice <= 0 and Sides <= 1:
    condition = "Start"
elif Dice >= 1 and Sides >= 2:
    print("You have selected", Dice," dice and", Sides,"Sides")
    condition = "play" 
    Roll1 = 0
    Roll2 = 0 
    Score1 = 0 
    Score2 = 0
while condition == "play": 
        Roll1 += randint(Dice,Sides)
        Roll2 += randint(Dice,Sides)
        print (name1,"'s Roll", Roll1) 
        print (name2,"'s Roll", Roll2)
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: it doesn't create an integer between the amount of sides and dice

Comment: or gives random values for example if i put one dice and 2 sides it would go up to 5 and 6 whereas it should only go upto 2 at most for a 2 sided dice

Comment: This is a general programming question and has nothing to do with  gamedev

Comment: @Bálint, it is a general programming question being specifically *applied* to game developing. [I brought this up on meta, a while back](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/generic-programming-questions-are-off-topic-period-right). It is very much on topic. At the very least, it is very much contested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a loop to simulate the number of dice there are to roll, and you seem to be using the `randint` function incorrectly.

*I haven't tested this code* but it should get you started:

```
condition = "Start" 
while condition == "Start": 
    Dice = int(input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (atleast 1)")) 
    Sides = int(input("Please select number of sides on dice you would like to use (atleast 2)")) 
    if Dice <= 0 and Sides <= 1:
        condition = "Start"
    elif Dice >= 1 and Sides >= 2:
        print("You have selected", Dice," dice and", Sides,"Sides")
        score = 0
        for i in range(Dice):
            roll = randint(1,Sides)
            score += roll
            print ("Die # ", i + 1, "'s Roll :", roll)
        print ("Score: ", score)
```

Basically, the `for` loop there will iterate over the number of dice roll that the user expected. With that, you don't need to create a variable for each roll.

And the `randint` method needs the min and max values. In the code you provided, you are mixing apples and oranges; `Dice` and `Sides` are not really related. What you want is the minimum value of one (the minimum value will be one for any dice), and the max value, as you could see, is the `Sides` variable, as you used.